# where is the command docker run in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019

I have created a simple asp.net core web app with docker support and VS automatically created a dockerfile with `ENTRYPOINT` and when I run using VS it works correctly. but where is the `docker run` command in Visual studio? and when I create a `docker.compose` it works correctly but where is the `docker-compose up` command in VS?

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the docker run command in Visual studio?Where is the
>   docker-compose up command in VS?

As I know, Docker-related commands is not in VS. Though you can add docker support when creating asp.net core projects in VS, this doesn't mean you can run `docker run` command inside VS IDE.

Please see [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for more details, you should install the [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/), after that configure the environment of docker container. Also `docker run` and `docker compose up` are commands used in **Docker Container** instead of VS, like the command used to configure the Shared Drives `docker run --rm -v ...`.

Comment: when debugging in VS you can see the commands docker-compose up is begin executed in VS console. where is this command stored?

Comment: @Hulk Hi, can [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/containerized-lifecycle/design-develop-containerized-apps/visual-studio-tools-for-docker#targetText=Docker%20support%20in%20Visual%20Studio%202017&targetText=Container%20orchestration%20support%2C%20via%20Docker,Docker%20Compose%20and%20Service%20Fabric.) helps to clarify your puzzle?` The developer workflow when using the Docker Tools included in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7 and later, is similar to using Visual Studio Code and Docker CLI (in fact, it's based on the same Docker CLI),`

Comment: Thanks for the info. but still VS is hiding the underlying docker-compose -up call.

Comment: Yes, I would think that VS only display the command message during the process. Can I know you're trying to find the location of docker.exe, or where the docker command message you see in VS are stored?

Comment: I am trying to locate where the docker command message in VS are stored.. It should be editable by developer.

Comment: Hi, this issue is related to bottom design, you may need to go [Dc](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to get help from product team.

Answer (score 1):

Build and run your image at least **once** from VS (The green play button). Go to the Output Window and select "Build Order" from the dropdown. Look for "docker run ..."

If you don't have an Output Window, go to the View tab and select **Output** from the drawdown.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).